# Cannot Find '-ldb' During Make

Tags: makefile, fedora

I am running `Fedora 24` on an `i386` system with `1GB RAM`.

I am attempting to run a Makefile and I am getting the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have used `dnf` to install the latest packages for `libdb` and `libdb-devel` but I am still getting the error - any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [`libdb-devel`](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/libdb-devel/). Running `sudo dnf install libdb-devel` should do the job. If not, make sure that the `/usr/lib/libdb.so` is in place on your system.

Also using `libdb-cxx-devel` might do the job.

Comment: Ah, so my `libdb.so` is linked to `/usr/lib/libdb.so.2` - which does not exist.  I have `libdb-4.so` and `libdb-5.so`.  What one should I be using?

Comment: Try to reinstall these packages: `sudo dnf reinstall libdb libdb-devel`.

Comment: Ah-ha!  I see what I've done wrong now!!!  Thanks a million for the help :)